# I am unit testing my angular 10 App and I need to set session item in spec.ts at runtime so that the code below executes without logging me out

Tags: angular, unit-testing

**Service:**

```
isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return !!(sessionStorage.getItem('access'));
}


checkAccess() {
    if (this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      this.getAccess();
    } else {
      this.logOut();
    }
  }
```

To avoid been logged-out as I unit test, I want to set the session so that **getAccess** in the **checkAccess** function above will execute.

**spec.ts:**

```
beforeEach(() => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('access', 'useraccess');    
});
```

This is not working for me as I always get looged-out. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got a work around this.

```
beforeEach(() => {
spyOn(AppLoaderService.prototype, 'checkAccess').call(() => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('access', 'userAccess');
});
```

});

With this, the test executes and the app runs successfully without logging me out so I get to see the test results displayed in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the test runner deal with mocks/stubs during test execution. If you're using Jasmine/Karma:

```
spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake(function (key) {
    return 'YOUR_ACCESS_VALUE';
});
```

if you're using Jest with Angular:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: {
    getItem: function (key) {
    return 'YOUR_ACCESS_VALUE';
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: The tests are executed successfully but chrome which is my test browser displays **NOT FOUND** . I don't see the test results in the browser. I need to set the session in spect.ts so that the service can access it for **isUserLoggedIn** to return true.